# In c++, why is cout is so important?

Tags: c++

I am new to C++. I have a question would like to ask here.

**Here is the original question:**

Given a decimal integer N, find the number of 1 in the corresponding binary number. I am trying to find out how many 1 in a binary number from an integer.

However I'm stuck with or without cout.
So I would like to know what is role does 'cout' play? Specifically in this line:

```
cout <<"Number of ones= "<< numOfOnes << endl;
```

Look at the two print results, drastically different without this above line.
Thank you.

my code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int n = 0;
    int num[n];
    cout << "Enter a set of integers: "<< endl;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> num[i];
    }
    cout << "num of arrays: "<< endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout << num[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int reminder = 0;
        int numOfOnes = 0;
        if(num[i] <= 0){
            numOfOnes = 0;
        }
        else{
            while (num[i] > 0){
                reminder = num[i] % 2;
                num[i] = num[i] / 2;
                cout <<" Reminder = "<< reminder<<endl;
                
                if( reminder == 1){
                    numOfOnes++;
                }
            }
        }
        cout <<"Number of ones= "<< numOfOnes << endl;
    }
}
```

Print:

```
num of arrays: 
2 100 1000 66 0 
 Reminder = 0
 Reminder = 1
Number of ones= 1
 Reminder = 0
 Reminder = 0
 Reminder = 1
 Reminder = 0
 Reminder = 0
 Reminder = 1
 Reminder = 1
Number of ones= 3
 Reminder = 0
 Reminder = 0
 Reminder = 0
 Reminder = 1
 Reminder = 0
 Reminder = 1
 Reminder = 1
 Reminder = 1
 Reminder = 1
 Reminder = 1
Number of ones= 6
 Reminder = 0
 Reminder = 1
 Reminder = 0
 Reminder = 0
 Reminder = 0
 Reminder = 0
 Reminder = 1
Number of ones= 2
Number of ones= 0
```

print without `'cout <<" Reminder = "<< reminder<<endl;"`

```
Number of ones= 1
Number of ones= 3
Number of ones= 0
Number of ones= 15
Number of ones= 0
```

####update: find the root cause, I decalred a array int num[n] before input the number n.

```
int n = 0;
int num[n];
cout << "Enter a set of integers: "<< endl;
cin >> n;
```

So a simple change is switch the int num[n]; after cin >> n.

So a working solution:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int n;
    cout << "Enter a set of integers: "<< endl;
    cin >> n;
    int num[n]; #changed here.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> num[i];
    }
    cout << "num of arrays: "<< endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << num[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int reminder = 0;
        int numOfOnes = 0;
        if(num[i] <= 0)
        {
            numOfOnes = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            while (num[i] > 0)
            {
                reminder = num[i] % 2;
                num[i] = num[i] / 2;
                //cout <<" Reminder = "<< reminder<<endl;

                if( reminder == 1)
                {
                    numOfOnes++;
                }
            }
        }
        cout <<"Number of ones= "<< numOfOnes << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has _undefined behavior_, so each little change might lead to different behavior.

Comment: `int n = 0;
    int num[n];` is invalid, and even with VLA extension, array of size 0... use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @Jarod42 works!!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 2:
Just change the  position of: int num[n];

#include 
    using namespace std;

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    // method 1:

    int n;
    cout << "Enter a set of integers: "<< endl;
    cin >> n;
    int num[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> num[i];
    }
    cout << "num of arrays: "<< endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << num[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int reminder = 0;
        int numOfOnes = 0;
        if(num[i] <= 0)
        {
            numOfOnes = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            while (num[i] > 0)
            {
                reminder = num[i] % 2;
                num[i] = num[i] / 2;
                //cout <<" Reminder = "<< reminder<<endl;

                if( reminder == 1)
                {
                    numOfOnes++;
                }
            }
        }
        cout <<"Number of ones= "<< numOfOnes << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Method 2 is not supported by Standard C++ (at least as of the 2017 revision) and is not guaranteed to work on all C++ compilers. For example, `int num[n];` will be rejected by Visual Studio.

Comment: It is working now! @user4581301 So I shouldn't use this method then

Comment: I prefer not to, but if your compiler supports variable length arrays by extension, use them with caution. The user can easily specify a value that causes `num` to exceed the space left on the stack for weird and sometimes difficult to spot results. `vector` will generate a an exception to warn you if you ask for too much. Variable length array leaves you to find out the hard way.

Comment: @user4581301 got it! Thank you so much